# how to read a php array to a java script variable in smarty?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, smarty

I am getting an array in php, and send it to smarty .tpl file.

In smarty I would like to get that array in a java script variable .

How to do this . Please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is parsed prior to any JS, you can simply add the values from the PHP array into a JS function:

So if you have this array in PHP:

```
$my_array = array("a","b","c","d","e");
```

Then you can use the following to initialize a JS array with the same values:

```
<?php
    //PHP snippet to create a comma-delimited string with each value of $my_array
    //surrounded by quotation marks.  Quotes not needed if values in array are numeric.
    $array_vals = '"' .implode('","', $my_array) .'"';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_array = [<?php echo $array_vals;?>];
</script>
```

Comment: Do not use `new Array`!
If you have `new Array(12)` array of 12 elements will be created. But if you have `new Array(12,13)` array of 2 elements [12,13] will be created.
If you assign array with only one element your code will not work as expected. See [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: @DamirR Of course you're right - edited my answer to correct that - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use json:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = <?= json_encode($arr) ?>;
</script>
```

`json_encode()` takes your php data and converts it into json, and in our case this is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should simple like

```
<?php
  $_array = array('apple','banana','durian');
  $js_array = '[' . implode(',',$_array) . ']';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var iArray = <?php echo $js_array;?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In php file just add like this

```
<?
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$jsarr = implode(',',$arr);
$smarty->assign(arr,$jsarr);
?>
```

in template file use it like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = new Array({$arr});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `[]` instead of `new Array`.
You need to put values in quotes and escape them - to be sure not to break js.
I realy don't like preprocessing data in php just to assign it to smarty.
This solves all potential problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr=[
    {foreach name=i from=$myarray item=v}
      '{$v|escape:"javascript"}'
      {if !$smarty.foreach.i.last},{/if}
    {/foreach}
    ];
</script>
```

if your array contains only integers the you can use `{$v|intval}`